# Comment @<username> sometimes does not appear

Tags: discussion

Majority of the time I am able to use @ to respond back to a user on SO, however in some instances it does not work? Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, you'll want to be more specific about what issue you're having.

Comment: Yes, that does answer my question. This is the part I was looking for "however if only you and the author have commented on the post so far, the @name will be automatically removed from the beginning of the comment, as it adds no value."